# HTML OnClick() event doesn't work

Tags: javascript, html, css, button, frame

It was working until I add `document.getElementById("frame").src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/"+frm;` line
But now even if I delete this part so make code like how it used to be and working fine, it still doesnt work. I have no idea if why it is like this. It might be a little detail which is I am missing now. Any ideas to find what it is ?

Also, I have tried to load `<p></p>` texts from a XML file but couldn't find a way for this too. It would be nice, if someone could help me to find a right method for this

```js
function bgClicked2 (idJ,pg,frm)
{
 var id = document.getElementById("bgMAIN");
 id.src="Pics/bgCLICKED2.png";
 var id2=document.getElementById("previews");
 id2.style.visibility="visible";
 document.getElementById("planet").src="Pics/"+idJ+".png";
  document.getElementById("frame").src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/"+frm;
  
}

function bgClicked()
{
 var id,prg,frame;
 id=document.activeElement.id;
 frame=document.activeElement.name;

 bgClicked2(id,"j",frame);
 alert("ughjnj");
 loadXMLDoc();
}
```

```css
p, li{
 font-size:17px;
 font-style:normal;
 color:#066;
 position:relative;
 float:right;
 word-wrap:break-word;
 width:651px;
 margin-left:35px; 
 
}
.button{
 position:absolute;
 margin-left:453px;
 margin-top:315px;
 z-index:2;
 border-radius:50%;
 border:none;
 size:50px;
 width:83px;
 height:89px;
 opacity:0;
}
```

```html
<center>
  <div class="upper"><img src="Pics/logo.png" width="75%" height="75%"/></div>
        <!--//<div><img src="Pics/2_.png" style="right:9px; top:12 position:relative;" /></div>-->
         <div class="spaceBoard">
        <input type="button" class="button"  onclick="bgClicked()  " id="sun" name="piuKlpJmjfg"/>
        <input type="button" class="world" onclick="j()" id="earth" name="pm7tfLvHmXA">
     <img src="Pics/bgMAIN2.png" id="bgMAIN">  
         <span id="previews" class="previews">
             <img src="Pics/sun.png" width="255" height="255" id="planet"/>
                <img src="Pics/back.png" width="39" height="39" style="float:right; margin-left:11" id="btnOut"/>
                <table style="float:right">
                <tr>
              <th><p id="paragraph">The sun is a star, a hot ball of glowing gases at the heart of our solar system. Its influence extends far beyond the orbits of distant Neptune and Pluto. Without the sun's intense energy and heat, there would be no life on Earth. And though it is special to us, there are billions of stars like our sun scattered across the Milky Way galaxy. If the sun were as tall as a typical front door, the Earth would be the size of a U.S. nickel. The temperature at the sun's core is about 27 million degrees Fahrenheit. Average diameter: 864,000 miles, about 109 times the size of the Earth.Rotation period at equator: About 27 days. Rotation period at poles: About 36 days. Surface temperature: 10,000 degrees Fahrenheit.Composition: Hydrogen, helium.</p></th>
                 </tr>
                 <tr>
                  <th><iframe id="frame" width="651" height="405" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/piuKlpJmjfg" frameborder="0" gesture="media" allow="encrypted-media" allowfullscreen></iframe></th>
                 </tr>
                 </table>
             
          </span>
        </div>
```

Comment: Do you see any errors in the console

Comment: There are none. Thats why I am confused

Comment: i cant find any function named j()  . also  what are the parameters in bgclicked2();

Comment: I am not able to replicate the issue

Comment: Have you tried doing a ctrl+f5 to force a refresh, the browser might have cached your broken version

Comment: Yes, the posted code works for me (with loadXMLDoc() being commented out). Are you clicking the right button? ;)

Comment: j is bgClicked(),  I have added this to code to see if I write the name wrong or not but I just didnt add here. id and frame is parameters for bgclicked2() the other one is just a random value, not from a variable

Comment: I have been refleshin the page like crazy but it just doesnt works on me but the site on webhost server (andromeda2.tk) works fine

Comment: as @Boardy said, try ctrl + f5 or delete stored files on cache or just generate versions of yours files (index.1.js => index.1.1.js)

Comment: it was thanks to a missing ' ; ' :) it is now working good. Thank anyways

Comment: What do you mean "doesn't work". What do you expect to happen when you press the button? What happens instead? When I press the button (which in this example seems to be invisible, I had to find it using the developer tools) it displays the alert box and then complains about `loadXMLDoc` not being defined, since you didn't include it in this example. Take a look at [mcve], it might help you improve this question and get a meaningful answer.

Comment: Calmn down, it is just a little part of the code I wrote here. It suppesed to load informations in main code (which is not written here) about planets when pressed and works good

Answer (score 2):

This looks like a browser cache issue. Try opening in incognito(private) mode or hard refresh using “Ctrl + F5”